# Acces function inside another function of the same class javascript

Tags: javascript, mongoose

If I try to call the `printTest` function inside `showMainPage` I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'print_tests' of undefined` , How can I access to the function?

```
showMainPage = function(req, res){
        var _this = this;
        Test.find({}).populate('user').exec(function(err, tests){
            console.log(tests);
            html = _this.printTests(tests, req.user.username);//the probllem its here

            res.render('main/index.twig', {
                tests: html,
                error: err
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: you'll have to return `_this` as an object from the `showMainPage` function and then call `showMainPage().printTests()`

Comment: You have a `this` context problem. what does a `console.log(this)` prints above the line `var _this = this;`?

Comment: this is undefined above `var _this = this;`

Comment: Post more code, your class definition